# Web form not sending data

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working on a [site](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/tuitionteacher/search.php?) where people can filter search results. The form doesn't seem to send the items when I click on submit button.

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" >
            City:<br>
              <input id="city"  value="">
            <hr>
            <!--
            Area:<br>
            <input id="area" placeholder="Select Area">
            <hr>
            -->
            Gender:<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<br>
            <hr>
            <!--
            <p>
                Age range:<br>
                <input  type="text" id="amount"/>
            </p>

            <div id="slider-range"></div>
            <hr>
            -->
            School:<br>
            <input id="school" >
            <hr>
            College:<br>
            <input id="college">
            <hr>
            University:<br>
            <input id="university">
            <hr>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Search</button>
            </form>
```

MySQL:

```
        <?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$city = $_GET["city"];
$gender = $_GET["gender"];
$school = $_GET["school"];
$college = $_GET["college"];
$university = $_GET["university"];


// $sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users WHERE city='$city' and gender='$gender' and school='$school' and college='$college' and university='$university'";
if(!empty ($city) and empty($gender) and empty ($school) and empty ($college) and empty ($university) )
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where city='$city' ";

elseif(!empty ($gender) and empty($city)  and empty ($school) and empty ($college) and empty ($university) )
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where gender='$gender' ";


elseif(!empty ($school) and empty($city)  and ($gender) and empty ($college) and empty ($university) ){
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where school='$school' ";
echo "229";
}

elseif(!empty ($college) and empty($city)  and empty ($school)  and empty ($gender) and empty ($college) and empty ($university) ){
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where college='$college' ";
echo "233";
}
elseif(!empty ($university) and empty ($city)  and empty ($school)  and empty ($gender)and empty ($college) and empty ($college) ){
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where university='$university' ";
echo "227";
}
elseif(!empty ($city) and !empty($gender) and empty ($school) and empty ($college) and empty ($university) ){
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where city='$city' and gender='$gender'";
echo "227";
}
elseif(!empty ($city) and empty($gender) and !empty ($school) and empty ($college) and empty ($university) ){

$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where city='$city' and school='$school'";
echo "242";
}
elseif(!empty ($city) and empty($gender) and empty ($school) and !empty ($college) and empty ($university) ){
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where city='$city' and college='$college'";
echo "245";
}
elseif(!empty ($city) and empty($gender) and empty ($school) and empty ($college) and !empty ($university) ){
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where city='$city' and university='$university'";
echo "248";
}
elseif(empty ($city) and !empty($gender) and !empty ($school) and empty ($college) and empty ($university) ){
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where gender='$gender' and school='$school'";
echo "251";
}
elseif(empty ($city) and !empty($gender) and empty ($school) and !empty ($college) and empty ($university) ){
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where gender='$gender' and college='$college'";
echo "254";
}
elseif(empty ($city) and !empty($gender) and empty ($school) and empty ($college) and !empty ($university) ){
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where gender='$gender' and university='$university'";
echo "257";
}
elseif(empty ($city) and empty($gender) and !empty ($school) and !empty ($college) and empty ($university) ){
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where school='$school' and college='$college'";
echo "260";
}
elseif(empty ($city) and empty($gender) and !empty ($school) and empty ($college) and !empty ($university) ){
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where school='$school' and university='$university'";
echo "263";
}
elseif(empty ($city) and empty($gender) and empty ($school) and !empty ($college) and !empty ($university) ){
$sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where college='$college' and university='$university'";
echo "279";
}

/*
if($city and $gender)
    $sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users where";
*/






else{
    $sql = "SELECT id,full_name, email, password,area,city,age,contact_number,gender,school,college,university FROM users";

    echo "295";
}

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Name:" . $row["full_name"]."<br> Email:". $row["email"]. "<br>City: " . $row["city"]. "<br>Age: " . $row["age"]. "<br>Contact Number:". $row["contact_number"]. "<br> Gender: " . $row["gender"]. "<br>School:" . $row["school"].  "<br> College:". $row["college"]."<br>University:" . $row["university"];
        echo "<br><hr>";
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: This is the form... where is the SQL?

Comment: you have varies input without the name attributes...maybe that is one of the problem?

Comment: @Kuya: I have added the MySQL with it.

Comment: These are all `select` statements... where is your `insert` statement`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inputs fields are missing `type` and `name` attribute. Try This:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" >
            City:<br>
              <input type="text" name="city"  value="">
            <hr>
            <!--
            Area:<br>
            <input type="text" name="area" placeholder="Select Area">
            <hr>
            -->
            Gender:<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male<br>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<br>
            <hr>
            <!--
            <p>
                Age range:<br>
                <input  type="text" name="amount"/>
            </p>

            <div id="slider-range"></div>
            <hr>
            -->
            School:<br>
            <input  type="text" name="school" >
            <hr>
            College:<br>
            <input  type="text" name="college">
            <hr>
            University:<br>
            <input  type="text" name="university">
            <hr>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Search</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: Your answer does not have `id` in it but it solved the problem after adding the id tags.

Comment: `id` is not important for `php` but for `javascript`. If you had any `javascript` operation with this than it is essential.

Comment: Since I had already used id in my html, its obvious that I am using the id tag for some task.